# TypeScript - Passing parameter in chained function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In node.js I'm making call a script with `exec` from `child_process`.

When in the closed state I want to check if there was any error so I can return it however I can't seem to access `error` in the second function `on()`.

Could someone kindly explain how I can pass it along.

```
exec('myScript.sh',
        (error: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => { }).on('close', () => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it outside of the callback function. If you look at the ES5 equivalent:

```js
exec("myScript.sh", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    // Do nothing
}).on("close", function() {
    // Cannot access error here
});
```

You can see that the scope of `error` is local to the anonymous callback function that is `exec`'s second argument. You can access it within the onclose callback function by storing it with a scope accessible to that function like so:

```
let execError = "";

exec("myScript.sh", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    execError = error;
}).on("close", function() {
    console.log(execError);
});
```

Or in your original notation (ES6):

```js
let execError: any = "";

exec("myScript.sh", (error: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => { 
    execError = error; 
}).on("close", () => { 
    console.log(execError); 
});
```